# What does this code mean?

Tags: javascript, html5

I got some code from here http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-game-character/1/

Everything is quite understandable, everything working well. However, I don't understand what breathDir could stand for.

```
function updateBreath() { 

  if (breathDir === 1) {  // breath in
    breathAmt -= breathInc;
    if (breathAmt < -breathMax) {
      breathDir = -1;
    }
  } else {  // breath out
    breathAmt += breathInc;
    if(breathAmt > breathMax) {
      breathDir = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: breath direction? If it's one, 'breathe in' and if it's not breath out? A boolean could have been used, named isBreathingIn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it does is make the 'breathAmt' variable travel go up and down between 1 and -1 over time.

This gets combined with the next snippet of code, about a few paragraphs down on the page:

```
function redraw() {

  canvas.width = canvas.width; // clears the canvas 

  drawEllipse(x + 40, y + 29, 160 - breathAmt, 6); // Shadow

  context.drawImage(images["leftArm"], x + 40, y - 42 - breathAmt);
  context.drawImage(images["legs"], x, y);
  context.drawImage(images["torso"], x, y - 50);
  context.drawImage(images["head"], x - 10, y - 125 - breathAmt);
  context.drawImage(images["hair"], x - 37, y - 138 - breathAmt);
  context.drawImage(images["rightArm"], x - 15, y - 42 - breathAmt);

  drawEllipse(x + 47, y - 68 - breathAmt, 8, 14); // Left Eye
  drawEllipse(x + 58, y - 68 - breathAmt, 8, 14); // Right Eye
}
```

The redraw you can see in the 'y' parameter the 'breathAmt' is being subtracted from another variable. In this case 'y' means height - so the images for the different body parts are being drawn at a very, very slightly different height depending on what the value of 'breathAmt' - which makes the character being drawn kind of look like he's breathing.